# Batch Scripting: Load One Directory Down Into Variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, scripting, directory

What I need to do is, without knowing the name of the directory, I need to load it into a variable so I can use it later in my script.

There should only be one directory. Something like:

```
    \\[server]\[directory]\**[profile]**
```

Without knowing the name, I need to load "Profile" into a .bat variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is only one directory? if not, what is the criteria to select the directory?

Comment: The directory name is specific to the persons computer.
Only 1 profile is copied from X computer, and then it is placed into a file on the server named after that computer.
Ultimately the server path will stay the same, the computer name will be known, but the profile copied is what won't be known.

In a different script, the user defines the profile copied.
In this script, I don't want to have to ask again, I just want to check for and copy down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will list everything in \SERVER\PATH, sorting such the directories are last (in case there are files), and sets 'name' to each: if there is only one directory, it will be the value you need

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /o-g /b \\SERVER\PATH') do set name=%%i
echo result = %name%
```

Comment: worked!
Fast and easy enough.

Thank you for your time.